# Ax 2012 component existence in all layers and models

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

Can anybody help me how to find a component existence in all layers and models installed in that layer. i.e find all the layers and models in which a particular component(ax 2012) exists.
For example how to find all the layers and models in which CustTable exists.
Is there any class or table that stores this information.
please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you need all models where *CustTable* is touched/modified or all models where this is used/referenced.

Comment: @Matej Yes i need all the model where this table is used and also respective layer of that model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comment is limited :(

Do you need to search through source code? Are you searching for merge candidates? Tell me your business requirement.

Here is the query returning elements that contains *CustTable* within selected models:

```sql
SELECT
   me.Name ElementName
   , Layer.Name Layer
   , mm.Name ModelName
   , ElementTypes.ElementTypeName
FROM ModelElement me
   JOIN ModelElementData med
      ON med.ElementHandle = me.ElementHandle
         AND me.ParentHandle = 0 -- only root elements
   JOIN ModelManifest mm
      ON mm.ModelId=med.ModelId
   JOIN Layer
      ON Layer.Id = med.LayerId
   JOIN ElementTypes
      ON me.ElementType = ElementTypes.ElementType
WHERE EXISTS (
   SELECT null
   FROM ModelElement child
      JOIN Sources s
         ON s.SourceHandle = child.ElementHandle
            AND s.LayerId = med.LayerId
            AND child.RootHandle = med.ElementHandle
   WHERE cast([SourceText] as nvarchar(max)) like '%CustTable%'
)
AND mm.Name IN ('Foundation','I4C')
```

Comment: i think i was not clear last time. My requirement is to find the all the layers and their models where a specified component is present. for eg a component 'CustTable' is present in SYS layer Foundation model and also in ISV layer I4C model. Then query should return me the SYS layer and its model Foundation and ISV layer and its model I4C, but the previous query returns the component usage in those layers and models which results in many records. according to my requirement there must be only 2 records is correct i.e 1st record |SYS | Foundation. 2nd record |ISV| I4C, please help me TIA.

Answer (score 2):

You can try search within *_model* databese with next query (this searcehs all *code* references - table, class, form, dataset, ...):

```sql
SELECT TOP 1000 [SourceHandle]
   , met.ElementTypeName
   , ro.Name object
   , me.Name method
   , l.Name Layer
   , mm.Name Model
   , cast([SourceText] as nvarchar(max)) sourceTxt
FROM [Sources] s
   join ModelElement me on me.ElementHandle=s.SourceHandle
      join ElementTypes met on met.ElementType=me.ElementType
   join ModelElement ro on ro.ElementHandle=me.RootHandle
   left join ModelElementData med on med.ElementHandle=s.SourceHandle and med.LayerId=s.LayerId and med.ElementHandle=me.ElementHandle
   left join Layer l on l.Id=s.LayerId
   left join ModelManifest mm on mm.ModelId=med.ModelId
WHERE cast([SourceText] as nvarchar(max)) like '%CustTable%'
```

If you need all records, remove `TOP 1000`.

Comment: where ro.Name = 'InventDim' using this in place of WHERE cast([SourceText] as nvarchar(max)) like '%CustTable%' will fetch the layers and models where this component is present. Is this right way to find the layers and models where a component is present.

Comment: `where ro.Name = 'InventDim'` will return all occurrences within *InventDim* table. 
If I understand you shoud use `WHERE cast([SourceText] as nvarchar(max)) like '%CustTable%' AND cast([SourceText] as nvarchar(max)) like '%InventDim%'`

- `ro`: root AOT node (table, class, ...)
- `me`: child AOT node (method)
- s: X++ source code

Comment: Actually i want to find the CustTable presence in layers and models. the above shows all occurrences. But i want the records like if CustTable is present in layer SYS and Model Foundation and Layer ISV model I4C. then i need to show as follows ComponentName | layer | model so i will get 2 records CustTable | SYS | Foundation and CustTable | ISV | I4C. can i filter like this, please help me in finding this. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    ro.Name object,
    ro.ElementType type,
    l.Name  Layer,
    mm.Name Model
FROM Sources s
    join ModelElement me on 
        me.ElementHandle = s.SourceHandle
    join ElementTypes met 
        on met.ElementType = me.ElementType
    join ModelElement ro 
        on ro.ElementHandle = me.RootHandle
    left join ModelElementData med 
        on  med.ElementHandle = s.SourceHandle 
        and med.LayerId       = s.LayerId 
        and med.ElementHandle = me.ElementHandle
    left join Layer l 
        on l.Id = s.LayerId
    left join ModelManifest mm 
        on mm.ModelId = med.ModelId
            where ro.Name = 'InventDim' order by mm.Name, ro.ElementType
```

In addition to the query suggested by the authors, a small change was made according to my requirement is giving the right results.